# Product of $n^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a formula that defines $$(1^1)(2^2)(3^3) . . . (n^n)?$$ Most of the texts on the internet tackle series with the same exponent, but how about this one?

Sorry for my mistakes

Comment: Is this what you seek for? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html

Comment: @uranix thanks!!!

Comment: This question would be better if you explained the context in which the formula showed up, or at least what you were hoping to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

The function you seek is called the hyperfactorial function, defined as $$H(n) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} k^k = 1^1 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 3^3 \cdots n^n$$

The OEIS sequence of integer values of $H(n)$ can be found [here](http://oeis.org/A002109).